# C# { get; set;} for different types of fields, stackoverflow exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dateTime fields which edited filled by datetimepicker with some format its fine, I need to use in different format so I created a new string property
and call it.
here how it looks;

```
public DateTime? birthDate_{ get; set; }
public string birthDate {
    get {
        return birthDate_!=null?birthDate_.Value.ToShortDateString():"";
    } 
    set { 
        birthDate = value; 
    } 
}
```

somehow whenever try to return this string property("birthDate") it throws

> "StackOverflowException"

Comment: `set { birthDate = value; }` - Your property is trying to set itself in its own setter.

Comment: There is a good reason to apply [capitalization conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
set { birthDate = value; }
```

The `birthDate` property is trying to set itself in its own setter.  Hence the infinite recursion.

Since this is a calculated property, it really shouldn't *have* a setter:

```
public string birthDate
{
    get
    {
        return birthDate_!=null ?
            birthDate_.Value.ToShortDateString() :
            "";
    }
}
```

Or, if you *want* it to have a setter, that setter should be setting the backing data property (`birthDate_`) instead of setting itself.  That would involve parsing the incoming `value` to a `DateTime`.

I suspect the root of the confusion here is coming form the naming and visibility of your properties.  Their names look like private member variables, which are commonly used in manually-implemented properties.  But they are actually public properties.  Stick with established naming conventions and it really does become more clear.

Comment: Yeah, actually  I understood why it throws this exception but removing setter made it work properly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @David stated: Your property is trying to set itself in its own setter.

You should set the private property in the setter of birthDate:

```
private DateTime? _birthDate;

public string BirthDate { get { return birthDate_!=null?
birthDate_.Value.ToShortDateString():""; } set { _brithDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value); } }
```

I've formatted your code to match the C# Coding Guidelines